# How to make ValueListenableBuilder build based on a condition from UI

Tags: flutter

I have multiple `ActivityButton` widgets that listen to same `ValueNotifier`.

```
class ActivityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActivityButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ActivityButtonState>(
        valueListenable: someModel.activityButtonStateNotifier,
        builder: (_, state, __) {
          return _buildContent(state);
        });
  }

  Widget _buildContent(ActivityButtonState state) { ... }
}
```

I use `ActivityButtonState` as value for `ValueNotifier`.

```
class ActivityButtonState {
    ActivityButtonState({required this.id, required this.text});
    final String id;
    final String text;
}
```

I want to scope the updates from `ValueNotifier` to be given to related `ValueListenebleBuilder` only by using `id` from `ActivityButtonState`. So, I updated constructor for `ActivityButton` like this:

```
const ActivityButton({Key? key, required this.scopeId}) : super(key: key);

final String scopeId;
```

Now, I don't know how to prevent rebuilds in `ValueListenableBuilder` if `id` from `ActivityButtonState` doesn't match `scopeId` in `ActivityButton`.

---

I have used `Selector` from `provider` package before. I need something similar so that `build` is triggered only if `id` matches.

---

Any help or alternatives appreciated.

Comment: you cannot do that, you would need to change the way `ValueListenableBuilder` rebuilds itself in [_valueChanged](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/5464c5bac7/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/value_listenable_builder.dart#L181-L183)

Comment: @pskink Yes, only a custom implementation of `ValueListenableBuilder` might do so. I guess `StreamBuilder` is out of possibilities as well. I was hoping to use inheritence somehow. Thank you for confirmation.

Comment: @pskink At most, `ValueNotifier` is set to new values two times a second. I am not sure if its ok. For now, I am returning empty `Container` when the `id` doesn't match. I thought about making `ActivityButton` stateful and then, adding a listener to source `ValueNotifier` so that I can `setState` only if condition matches, but this seems too extreme.

Comment: so I would create a thin wrapper that extends `ValueNotifier` and takes `ValueListenable` and a test callback in the constructor and notifies listeners only when test callback returns true

Comment: something like this: `class ConditionalNotifier<T> extends ValueNotifier<T> {
final ValueListenable<T> parent;
final bool Function(T value) notifyWhen;

ConditionalNotifier({
required this.parent,
required this.notifyWhen,
}) : super(parent.value);

@override
void addListener(VoidCallback listener) {
super.addListener(listener);
parent.addListener(_listener);
}

@override
void removeListener(VoidCallback listener) {
super.removeListener(listener);
parent.removeListener(_listener);
}

void _listener() {
if (notifyWhen(parent.value)) {
value = parent.value;
}
}
}`

Comment: @pskink thank you, you can add it as an answer. Also, I couldn't understand how removing listener is working. How does `parent` identifies `_listener` to be the same listener that was added before? If you explain that it will be helpful.

Comment: *"How does parent identifies _listener to be the same listener that was added before?"* - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ee4e09cce0/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L243